# Increased body heat after workout when in bed

Tags: sleep

I am little overweight, 120 kg, from India. When I go to bed after a workout in the gym, say for 30 minutes, I can't sleep as my body begins to heat up.

Are there any remedies? I tried showering, but it didn't help.

Comment: At what time are you exercising, right before going to bed?

Comment: How is your hydration? Are you sweating during your workout? Have you taken your temperature before and after a workout to determine what the change actually is?

Comment: Hi Chuck  I have high body temrature,sweat a lot

Answer (score 1):

When you work out, your heart rate rises and your metabolism reaches a higher rate. After I workout, my metabolic rate remains quite high for over an hour, so I cannot work out effectively in the evening and then go to bed (my problem is that it makes me very alert, the heat is less of an issue in Scotland:-)

So my solution is to work out first thing in the morning - this also gives me a boosted start to the day. See if you can change your workout time to the morning - it may make all the difference you need.

Comment: Actually I from from India,and already have body heat,wake up late